# Regular expression to match character repeated three times

Tags: regex

I need to simplify the following regular expression to include all the letters of the alphabet:

```
(a{3})|(b{3})|(c{3})|(z{3})|(A{3})|(B{3})|(C{3})|(Z{3})
```

In practice I want to find all the sequences of same three chars, for example:

```
aaa
bbb
nnn
VVV
JJJ
```

and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use backreferences. Eg. in sed:

```
\([a-zA-Z]\)\1\1
```

or in PERL regular expressions

```
([a-zA-Z])\1\1
```

Answer (score 10):

A regular expression using backreferences would be suitable.

```
([a-z])\1{2}
```

So something along the lines of `preg_match('/([a-z])\1{2}/i', $string);` would suffice.