# Regular expression to find return of character for 5 times

Tags: java, regex, sequence, fsm

I'm trying to build a finite state machine and I want to check the sequence that I get, with a regular expression.
I need to check if the sequence is from the the following form:

For example:

`"A,B,C,C,C,C,C,A"` -> is accepted.

`"A,B,C,C,C,C,A"` -> is ignored.

`"A,B,C,C,C,C,C,C,A"` -> is ignored.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732852/regular-expression-to-match-character-repeated-three-times) and that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147810/regular-expression-same-character-3-times), but everything I tried simply doesn't work.

I tried the next things: `A\B\D{5}\A`, `ABD{5}A` and a couple more, but again with no success.

**EDIT:** I want to know if the C character is return exactly 5 times, before and after doesn't matter at all, meaning it could be like this also:

A,A,A,F,F,R,E,D,C,C,C,C,C, ......

Don't consider the commas.

The problem is that I need to find if a sequence is accepted but, the sequence is from the next form: 
A,B, C*10, 
I created the machine class, the state class and the event class.
But now I need to know if I have exactly 5 returns of C, and it causing me a lot of problems.

**EDIT:**
It's not working, see the code Iv'e added.

```
String sequence1 = "A,B,C,C,C,C,A";
String sequence2 = "A,B,C,C,C,C,C,A";
String sequence3 = "A,B,C,C,C,C,C,C,A";
Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w)(?:,\\1){4}");
Matcher m = mPattern.matcher(sequance1);
m.matches(); //FALSE
Matcher m = mPattern.matcher(sequance2);
m.matches(); //FALSE
Matcher m = mPattern.matcher(sequance3);
m.matches(); //FALSE
```

It's returning always false.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `AB..`? Should your string always start with `AB..`?

Comment: @Rohit Jain Let's say he could start with anything, this is only for example.

Comment: What is is you want the regex to match, exactly?  The whole string?  The `C`s each individually?  The repeated sequence of 5 `C`s?

Comment: Tell us exactly what you want

Comment: If there are commas in the strings you probably need to take that into account...

Comment: Could you show us your actual strings and the code you have tried, please?

Comment: @OfirA... In that last example has only `4 C's`. That regex is for `5 C's`. Of course it won't work.

Comment: @Rohit Jain This is only for the example here. Everything I tried isn't working, yes, also with 5 C's.

Comment: @OfirA... Don't use `m.matches()`. It will try to match the whole string, which will return false.. Use `m.find()`, which searches for that pattern in string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is not working because you are not considering the comma in your string, which I assume is available.

You can try the following regex (I'm posting here a generalized pattern, you can modify it accordingly): -

```
"(\\w)(?:,\\1){4}"
```

This will match any 5 sequence of same characters separated by comma.

`\1` is used to backreference the 1st matched character, and the rest of the 4 characters should be the same as that.

**Explanation: -**

```
"(         // 1st capture group
   \\w     // Start with a character
 )
 (?:       // Non-capturing group
    ,      // Match `,` after `C`
    \\1    // Backreference to 1st capture group. 
           // Match the same character as in (\\w)
 ){4}"     // Group close. Match 4 times 
           // As 1st one we have already matched in (\\w)
```

**UPDATE: -**

If you just want to match `5 length` sequence, you can add a negation of the matched character after the 5th match: -

```
"(\\w)(?:,\\1){4}(?!,\\1)"
```

`(?!,\\1)` -> Is negative look-ahead assertion. It will match 5 consecutive character that are not followed by the same character.

**UPDATE: -**

In the above Regex, we also need to do a negative look-behind for `\\1` which we can't do. So, I came up with this wierd looking Regex. Which I myself don't like, but you can try it whether it works or not: -

*Not Tested*: -

```
"(\\w),(^\\1)(?:,\\2){4}(?!,\\2)"
```

**Explanation: -**

```
(       // First Capture Group
  \\w   // Any character, before your required sequence. (e.g. `A` in `A,C,C,C,C,C`)
)       // Group end
,       // comma after `A`

(          // Captured group 2
   ^\\1    // Character other than the one in the first captured group. 
           // Since, We now want sequence of `C` after `A`
)
(?:        // non-capturing group
   ,       // Match comma
   \\2     // match the 2nd capture group character. Which is different from `A`, 
           // and same as the one in group 2, may be `C`

){4}       // Match 4 times

(?!        // Negative look-ahead
    ,
    \\2    // for the 2nd captured group, `C`
)
```

I don't know whether that explanation makes the most sense or not. But you can try it. If it works, and you can't understand, then I'll try to explain a little better.

Comment: Including the `,` in the capturing group is not a good idea, it requires a comma after the fifth character ==> this would not match "A,B,C,C,C,C,C".

Comment: @Rohit Jain Can you please elaborate more of how you build it, I want to totally understand it, Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit Jain Thanks for your explanation. The problem, like stema said, is that this will match 5 identical letters, but it will match also if I have more. Is there any way to not afford it, meaning only 5 returns of the same letter?

Comment: @OfirA... Yes you can do it. Just add a negation of the captured character after the 5 matches. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @OfirA... See my last regex. That should do what you want.

Comment: This will not help `^` is an anchor for the start of the string and not the negation of the following. You would need to work with lookaround assertions, something like `(?<!\\1,)(\\w)(?:,\\1){4}(?!,\\1)`, but I am quite sure you can't use a reference before you actually match it.

Comment: @stema.. Well, we don't need a negative look behind.. Just negative look ahead will work.

Comment: @stema.. Oh Damn.. We do need negative look behind here. But we can't. Let me think of some other way.

Comment: @stema.. I have come up with an alternative. You can take a look at that, and confirm whether you can understand it.

Comment: @OfirA... You can try the last regex with 7 continuous character `C` and see whether it works. And then with `5 characters`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'll check it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you have tried, but you don't need to escape letters to match them.

I am not sure what your requirements are, but to find 5 repeated characters you can use this:

```
(\\p{L})(?:,\\1){4}
```

This would find all letters that are repeated 5 times. See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32okm).

On Regexr I used `\w` because `\p{L}` is not supported there, but it is in Java.

`\p{L}` is a Unicode property matching every letter in any language.

1. The idea here is to match a letter. This is done by `\\p{L}`.
2. This letter is stored in a backreference because there are the brackets around `(\\p{L})`.
3. Then there is the non-capturing group `(?:,\\1)`. This matches a comma and the `\\1` is a reference to the letter captured before.
4. This non-capturing group is repeated 4 times `(?:,\\1){4}`.

==> as result this pattern matches on 5 identical letters with commas between.

The problem here is, this expression will match at least 5 identical letters. If there are more of them it will also (partly) match.

**Update:**

I don't see a chance to get the result directly from a regex. But here is a method to get the length indirectly:

```
String[] TestInput = { "A,B,C,C,C,C,C", "A,B,C,C,C,C,C,D,E",
        "C,C,C,C,C", "C,C,C,C,C,D,E", "A,B,C,C,C,C", "C,C,C,C",
        "A,B,C,C,C,C,C,C,D,E", "C,C,C,C,C,C,D,E", "C,C,C,C,C,C" };

// Match at least 5 letters in a row
// The letter is in group 2
// The complete found sequence is in group 1
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\p{L})(?:,\\2){4,})");

for (String t : TestInput) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
        if (m.find()) {

            // Get the length of the found sequence, after the commas has
            // been removed
            int letterLength = m.group(1).toString().replace(",", "")
                    .length();
            // Check your condition of exactly 5 equal letters
            if (letterLength == 5) {
                System.out.println(t + " ==> " + true);
            } else {
                System.out.println(t + " ==> " + false);
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println(t + " ==> " + false);
        }
}
```

Output:

> A,B,C,C,C,C,C ==> true
>   A,B,C,C,C,C,C,D,E ==> true
>   C,C,C,C,C ==> true
>   C,C,C,C,C,D,E ==> true
>   A,B,C,C,C,C ==> false
>   C,C,C,C ==> false
>   A,B,C,C,C,C,C,C,D,E ==> false
>   C,C,C,C,C,C,D,E ==> false
>   C,C,C,C,C,C ==> false

Comment: Can you please elaborate more of how you build it, I want to totally understand it, Thanks.

Comment: @OfirA. Added some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You said that if I have more then 5 identical letters, it will also be a match. Is there any way to not afford it, meaning only 5 returns of the same letter?

Comment: @OfirA. I added a new solution.